Calculating the minimum surface area of a $1$dm thick cork sheet to float in water and support a $70$kg person, if cork's density is $0.24$ g/cm$^2$
An Archimedes' principle problem:

We have a $1$ dm thick cork sheet. Calculate the minimum surface area that it should be used to float in water, supporting a $70$ kg castaway. The density of cork is 0.24 g/cm$^2$.

Note: we understand the minimum surface area to be that which allows the man to be kept completely outside.
of the water even if the board is completely immersed in it.
$$p_c=240 \frac{kg}{m^3}$$
$$1dm = 0.1m$$
I was trying:
$$m_hg=Vp_cg$$
$$A = \frac{m_h}{p_c (h)}= 2.91m^2$$
but this is not true what did I get wrong?

The cork's density is given in area density "0.24 g/cm$^2$", while the thickness is only $1~\text{dm}$, then the density using volume would be $0.24~\text{g$/$cm$^2/$dm} = 24~\text{kg$/$m$^3$}$ instead?

@peterwhy It is most likely a typo. The density of a typical cork is around $0.24 \frac{\text{g}}{\text{cm}^3} = 240 \frac{\text{kg}}{\text{m}^3}$. For reference, the density of cotton is typically around $80 \frac{\text{kg}}{\text{m}^3}$.

One liter is 1 dm${}^3$, one liter of water weights around 1 kg, so a submerged 1 dm cube of cork weigths 0.24 kg and thus supports 0.76 kg above the water. Now divide $70/.76=92.1$ which is the needed area in dm$^2$.

For more unclarity of the problem statement: the area of one flat side of the cork sheet is around $92~\text{dm}^2 = 0.92~\text{m}^2$, but what is the minimum surface area of such cork sheet? The surface area would be at least twice of the base area, plus the minimum lateral area derived from the minimum circumference.

A good hint that something is not right is that you are not using the density of water, which is obviously important. Let's write and solve a vertical force balance on the cork.
The weight of the cork is $\rho_c A h_s g$, and the downward force from the castaway person standing on top is $m_p g$. (Here, I am using $h_s$ to denote the submerged depth of the cork.) From Archimedes' principle, the upward buoyant force from the water on the cork is $\rho_w A h_s g$. If the cork is to float, we should have $h_s \le h$, where $h$ is the height of the cork. We thus have
$$0 \le (\rho_w - \rho_c) A h g - m_p g$$
$$\implies A \ge \frac{m_p}{(\rho_w - \rho_c) h}$$
Substituting your values, with $\rho_w \approx 10^3 \frac{\text{kg}}{\text{m}^3}$, we find
$$A \ge \frac{70 \text{ kg}}{\left( 10^3 \frac{\text{kg}}{\text{m}^3} - 240 \frac{\text{kg}}{\text{m}^3} \right) (0.1 \text{ m})} \approx 0.92 \text{ m}^2$$

How is $ h_s$ = $0$ instead of some negative value?

@samsamradas $h_s \ne 0$; it is equal to $h$ at the minimum area. We are using $h_s$ to denote the magnitude of the submerged depth.

can you elaborate more your first inequality

@samsamradas Sure. Static equilibrium gives $0 = (\rho_w - \rho_c) A h_s g - m_p g$. Now, for the cork to "float", we should have $h_s \le h$. Substitute and you will obtain the first inequality.

You explain very well sir thank you
